# Why is the sum of INT(RND*100)+1 always equal to 0? _QBasic

Tags: qbasic

I'm writing a guessing game in QBasic , which kind of tells you that im not to this, and every time I run the code the rndnum is always 0. what should i change?

Comment: Show us the complete code, otherwise we cannot help you. Also, qbasic is getting a bit old, there are many alternatives these days for beginners. I would suggest looking into Python or any other more modern language, you will find much more help online.

Comment: Show us some code. Have you initialized the random generator? What does RND return?

Comment: http://brisray.com/qbasic/qchance.htm

Comment: Some Basic dialects require a parameter such as RND(1)

Answer (score 1):

To get a different random number you must first seed it. Here's the example from the QB 4.5 Help file:

```
RANDOMIZE TIMER  ' This is the best seed. The time is constantly changing
A =  INT(RND*100)+1 ' Generate a random number
Print A
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the very first returned number is zero every time the program is run then all you need is to add the randomize statement as a one-time called procedure.  If you are instead saying that as you are iterating through the same code in a loop it is returning zero every time then there is something else wrong - most likely that for whatever reason QBasic does not recognize RND as a function and therefore assumes it's a variable, which would by default be set to zero.  The correct syntax would be something like:

```
Lowerbound = 1
Upperbound = 100
RANDOMIZE
FOR X = 1 TO 10
  PRINT INT((Upperbound - Lowerbound + 1) * RND + Lowerbound)
NEXT X
```